# inserting divs after certian divs with JQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, loops

I have divs that are being displayed via a WordPress loop.. about 60 thumbnail images that link to posts (a lot of thumbnails, I know).. and they are all in divs, obviously. :)  I would like to insert these divs after whichever post divs I chose... in jQuery. As far as I know, you can do something similar with `insertAfter`...

`$('.test').insertAfter('.inner');`

But I would like to insert divs after a specific number of my post divs that are being displayed via my WordPress loop.. so I would like to insert a div after the 10th, 20th, 30th, 40th and 50th post thumbnail divs.

Is this possible in jQuery, and if so how would I go about doing it?

Comment: "obviously", nope, nothing is obvious.

Comment: really? like, really? your going to give me a vote down on my question because i used the word "obviously".. thats just sad. no offense.

Comment: No, I commented. Someone else voted the question down. I'm just saying the question isn't clear.

Comment: My question is very clear, I'm asking how to insert divs after other divs via jquery.

Comment: OK, I'm wrong, it's clear as a bell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the children you want (your ~60 divs):

```
$( ".parent div" )
```

Then, filter out every child except every nth item:

```
$( ".parent div:nth-of-type(10n)" )
```

Then you can insert your `<p>` after every element in the set:

```
$( ".parent div:nth-of-type(10n)" ).after( "<p>Test</p>" );
```

Comment: hey man, your way seems the most practical for me so I went with it!... I can't seem to get it working though, it just returns text that says ".test" instead of the actual .test div.  and also it displays 4 of them instead of 2... here is the jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem.. http://jsfiddle.net/EUqEm/ if you could help me out with getting the jsfiddle working that would be great! thanks for the help so far dude. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `filter` and modulus operator:

```
$('.inner').filter(function(i) { return i % 10 === 0; }).after('...');
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do that with `$.eq`. Here is the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
var max_post = 1000;
var divs = $("div.inner");
for(var index = 10; index < max_post; index+=10)
{
     var obj = divs.eq(index);
     $('.test').insertAfter(obj);
}
```

Comment: Won't this end up being a bit inefficient? Each time around the loop, you need to get all the `$("div.inner")` divs, and then filter them. Seems like you might want to get them all outside the loop and then apply `eq` inside your loop.

Comment: @aquinas, what do you meant? can you update my answer for the change?

Comment: Here's an example that shows what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/9teFD/. I updated your answer too.